# How to remove windows.h calls from application?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++

I have an application that uses windows.h but I am tasked with removing the calls to Windows functions.

I am using Visual Studio Express 2010 and when I delete the `#include "windows.h"` line the code is still able to compile and I can right click and "Go To Definition" for all the variables associate with the windows include file.

I removed `$(WindowsSdkDir)include;` from the VC++ Directories in the Configuration Properties page but that didn't seem to make a difference. I believed that could be the case because windows.h can be found at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\windows.h` on my computer.

How do I completely break this link so Visual Studio can give me errors for all calls to that library?

Comment: Maybe you are using precompiled headers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the /showIncludes command switch to search for indirect includes of windows.h

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk.aspx